# How to add a style to <iframe> tag using javascript when it's parent tag's id is known?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to apply a style to an iframe whose parent tag's id is known??

Example:

```
<div id="xyz"> 
 <iframe ....> </iframe>
</div>
```

I want to apply style to iframe as `height: 70px`.
I just got to know how to do this using CSS.

How can I do that using javascript. Any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// grab the div and the first iframe inside it:

var iframe = document.getElementById('xyz').getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];

// There are two different valid ways to set the height

// 1. Change the attribute like it was <iframe height="70" ... />
iframe.height = '70';

// 2. Change the attribute like it was <iframe style="height: 70px;" ... />
iframe.style.height = '70px';
```